# MongoDB - Sorting / Merging multiple embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, sorting, merge, documents

I’m quite new with mongoldb.

I have a question that I cannot resolve by myself.

This is my model (simplified for the scope of this question)

```
account {
type: String
videos: [video],
images: [image]
}

video {
name: String,
length: Number,
Date: Date
}

image {
name: String,
size: Number
Date: Date
}
```

so a main model Account with two embedded documents: videos and images.

I would like to (in this sequence):

1. query all the accounts by type
2. sort both videos and images arrays by Date
3. get the list of images and videos
4. limit the output in order to do a pagination

Is it possible or is preferable change the model?

Example:

Source

```
[{ 
type: 2, 
images: 
       [{ name: 'imagetest1', size: 3, Date: 2011-01-01}, 
       { name: 'imagetest2', size: 13, Date: 2011-02-02}], 
videos: 
       [{ name: 'videotest1', length: 24, Date: 2011-01-07}, 
       { name: 'videotest2', length: 15, Date: 2011-03-02}] }
{
type: 2, 
images: 
       [{ name: 'imagetest3', size: 3, Date: 2011-01-03}, 
       { name: 'imagetest4', size: 15, Date: 2011-01-06}], 
videos: 
       [{ name: 'videotest3', length: 24, Date: 2011-02-05}, 
       { name: 'videotest4', length: 16, Date: 2011-02-04}] 
},
{
type: 1, 
images: 
       [{ name: 'imagetest5', size: 3, Date: 2011-01-03}, 
       { name: 'imagetest6', size: 15, Date: 2011-01-06}], 
videos: 
       [{ name: 'videotest5', length: 24, Date: 2011-02-05}, 
       { name: 'videotest6', length: 16, Date: 2011-02-04}] 
}]
```

MongoDB query:

Query account by type: 2, sort both images and video by data ascending and finally merge images and video in one array.

Output

```
[{ name: 'imagetest1', size: 3, Date: 2011-01-01},
{ name: 'videotest1', length: 24, Date: 2011-01-02}, 
{ name: 'imagetest3', size: 3, Date: 2011-01-03},
{ name: 'videotest4', length: 16, Date: 2011-02-04},
{ name: 'videotest3', length: 24, Date: 2011-02-05},
{ name: 'imagetest4', size: 15, Date: 2011-01-06},
{ name: 'videotest1', length: 24, Date: 2011-01-07},
{ name: 'imagetest2', size: 13, Date: 2011-02-02},
{ name: 'videotest2', length: 15, Date: 2011-03-02}]
```

Comment: the following command will sort based on video.date and then on image date
    db.account.find({type: "type you want"}).sort({video.date: true, image.date:true}).limit(count)  I dont think its possible to do sorting at the database level unless you do it after retrieving from mongodb

Comment: I have updated the question in order to make it more clear. I don't want to sort and merge the output after the retriving, if possible I want to do all at database level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with help of MAP-REDUCE.

**Map function :**

```
var map = function()
{

var doc = this.videos;

for( var i =0 ; i < this.images.length; i++ )
{
doc.push({name: this.images[i].name, length : this.images[i].size, Date: this.images[i].Date});
}

emit(this.type, doc );
}
```

**Reduce Function :**

```
var reduce = function(k,v)
{
 var arr = v[0];
 for( var j = 1 ; j < v.length; j++ )
  {
    arr = arr.concat(v[j]);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

**Query :**

```
db.accounts.mapReduce(
                       map,
                       reduce,
                       { 
                         out : {inline: 1} ,
                         query : {type : 2} , 
                         sort : {Date : 1}
                       }
                     );
```

In the future releases of [MongoDb 3.2](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) you can use [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) operator to merge the Arrays in aggregation pipeline easily.

```
db.accounts.aggregate([
{
  $match : { type: 2 }
},
{
  $project : 
            { 
             newArray:  
                  { $concatArrays: [ {$ifNull: ["$videos", [] ] }, {$ifNull: ["$images", [] ] } ] } ,
             type : 1
            } 
},
{
  $sort : {"$newArray.Date" : 1 }
}
]);
```

Comment: This is the best answer. However, I have resolved changing the model merging videos and image embedded documents.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

From my point of view, you have to correlate your queries to the point in time they are needed.

For example: Do you **really** need all this information immediatel? More often than not, you don't. So let us dissect those queries. Here is what I would come up with

1. At a given point in time, what are the users matching a given type?
2. *For a given user*, what are the videos, sorted by date at a given point in time?
3. *For a given user*, what are the images, sorted by date at a given point in time?
4. For a given user's videos, what are the contents of page x of size y?
5. For a given user's images, what are the contents of page x of site y?

The reason why I would split it like this is simply user experience. Let's assume a given user opens a web page showing his images and videos. By splitting the questions, you could load them independently via AJAX – But the user at least already has his or her page. By making the queries as simple as possible, they are most likely answered quicker. So, let's have a look at the actual queries and how to speed them up.

### The models

I would simply split those models, since a) there is a 16MB BSON size limit, b) In the default mmapv1 storage engine, expanding documents in size beyond a certain threshold causes an expensive document migration, c) As you see, complicated models lead to complicated queries for answering simple questions.

So, we split our models

#### The user model

```js
{
  _id: new ObjectId(),
  username: "SomeUserName",
  type: "someType"
  //… Whatever you deem appropriate
}
```

#### The video model

```js
{
  _id: new ObjectId(),
  owner: objectIdOfUser,
  name: "cool video",
  duration: msecsAsLong,
  date: new ISODate()
}
```

Since our question regarding the videos is for a *given* user, we can use an implicit reference here instead of embedding.

#### The images model

The same applies to images:

```js
{
  _id: new ObjectId(),
  owner: objectIdOfUser,
  name: "Some image name",
  size: bytesAsLong,
  Date: new ISODate()
}
```

### Answering the questions

#### "At a given point in time, what are the users matching a given type?"

The query is pretty easy:

```js
db.users.find({"type":typeToLookup})
```

Optimizing this query is equally easy:

```js
db.users.createIndex({"type":1})
```

#### "*For a given user*, what are the videos/images, sorted by date at a given point in time?"

Since we split the questions, we simplified everything. The query to answer this question becomes rather trivial, too *as we have a known user we want to get the videos for*:

```js
db.videos.find({ "owner": knownUserId }).sort({ "date":-1 })
```

for descending order or

```js
db.videos.find({ "owner":knownUserId }).sort({ "date":-1 })
```

for ascending order. Optimizing the query depends on wether you want ascending or descending order:

```js
// For descending order
db.videos.createIndex({ "owner":1, "date":-1 })

// For ascending order
db.videos.createIndex({ "owner":1, "date":1 })
```

Note that you can use both indices for an vice versa ordering, though they won't be as efficient. What I tend to do is to create the index according to the default ordering, as the user usually can live with a short time when ordering is reversed.

The images work accordingly.

#### For a given user's videos/images, what are the contents of page x of size y?

This is trivial, now. We have decided for an ordering, let's say descending. Now, we simply use skip and limit. Let's say your page size is 10 and you want to see the second page of the videos of a user in descending order of their date:

```js
var pageSize = 10
var pageToDisplay = 2
var recordsToSkip = pageSize * (pageToDisplay - 1)
db.videos.find({ "owner": knownUserId }).sort({date:-1}).skip(recordsToSkip).limit(pageSize)
```

Again, the images work accordingly.

### Why should one use that approach?

As written, with embedding, you are likely to hit the BSON document size limit imposed by MongoDB. Furthermore, we prevent rather costly document migrations and made complicated queries extremely easy while still giving answer to the same questions.

It might well be that the example shown above does not exactly fit your use case. But you get the picture of the "divide and conquer" approach for solving problems.